# Dropbox folder downloads as 'unspecified' file

Tags: dropbox, download

I'm trying to download a folder from Dropbox. When I click download, all I get is a file called `unspecified`. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when you have "too many" files in that folder.

From the Dropbox Help Center:
https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/49

> Can I download entire folders on the Dropbox website?
>
> Note: It's not possible to use the website to download an entire folder that's **over 1 GB or that has over 10,000 files**. If the folder is in your account, use the Dropbox desktop application to download the entire folder to your computer automatically.

A workaround that I've found is to simply download the directory in chunks, by selecting (click and <kbd>shift</kbd>+click) a block of files that is below this limit.